# Remotely wiping an iPhone which doesn't open

Tags: iphone, ios, icloud, find-my-iphone

My iPhone 6s (iOS 11) is not powering on, and in order to bring it for service, I have been asked to remove it from my iCloud account first. From what I have understood, removing it from my account will keep it locked with my passcode and won't erase the device. Do I need to erase it before removing it from the account?

I checked [Apple's documentation](https://support.apple.com/kb/PH2702?locale=en_US), which doesn't clarify whether an iPhone configured to be erased will do so when coming online after having been removed from the iCloud account. Specifically for removing it from the account it mentions:

> If the device is offline, the remote erase begins the next time it’s
>   online. You receive an email when the device is erased.
>
> When the device is erased, click Remove from Account.

So in case of sending a remote erase command and removing a device from the account, will it still be erased? Or do I need to wait for the successful erase e-mail before removing the device from the account?

Comment: The linked Apple knowledge base article also mentions: `If you no longer have the iOS device, Apple Watch, or Mac because you gave it away or sold it, you need to remotely erase it before you can remove it.` Does that answer your query? It also states, `When the device is erased, click Remove from Account.`.

Comment: I think it's not clear from this quote either if the remote wipe will take place if the device has been removed from the account.

Comment: Yes, there appears to be an ambiguity in the statement. IMO it's safer to wait for the erase acknowledgement before removing the device from iCloud.